# Character (empty) when using html_nodes and gadget selector

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am scraping some data from a website, using rvest package and gadget selector. The gadget selector tells me that to scrape the data I'm interested in I should write 'erogazioni_intervent' as an argument in html_nodes() function (see the code below). However, once I run the code, it does not retrive any data. I don't understand why, since I managed to scrape data quite easily applying the same method to other websites.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)

link <- "https://artbonus.gov.it/lista-interventi.html"
page <- read_html(link)

amount <- page%>%
  html_nodes('erogazioni_intervent')%>%
  html_text()

database <- data.frame(amount,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I also tried inserting a dot (.erogazioni_intervent) but nothing changes.

Comment: can you check the structure of your `page` object - does it look like valid xml?  (`rvest` imports `read_html()` from `xml2`).  Does it contain the text "erogazioni_intervent" anywhere?  Also, `html_node()` is superseded - `html_element()` is used now in rvest since v1.0.0

Comment: As of why -- the page is rendered by javascript and those selectors are not present in the page source that is parsed by rvest. Few Q/A on the same topic - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brvest%5D+disable+javascript .